# Yum is broken on CentOS 6.2

Tags: python, centos, rpm, yum

I had overwritten /usr/bin/python with Python 2.7 earlier. CentOS requires Python 2.6.6 But I have since reinstalled Python 2.6.6. However yum is still not working.

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

My Python 2.6.6 installation appears to be missing yum site packages:

```
# rpm -V yum
...
missing     /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum
...
```

Where should I install Python 2.6.6 from?

Answer (score 0):

Directory `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum` belongs to yum package (as it is reported as missing when you verify yum package), so reinstall `yum` package to get it fixed. It is possible that other packages which install files into `/usr/lib/python2.6/` have lost its files as well, so there might be similar issues for them.